# Need explanation for the proof of Theorem 46.8 in Munkres Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This is the theorem: Let $X$ be a space and let $(Y, d)$ be a metric space. On the set $\mathscr C(X, Y )$, the compact-open topology and the topology of compact convergence coincide.

I understand the part of the proof that is about why the topology of compact convergence is finer than the compact-open topology. I don't understand the following statement in the proof about why the compact-open topology is finer than the topology of compact convergence:

> Each point $x$ of $X$ has a neighborhood $V_x$ such that $f(\bar{V}_x)$ lies in an open set $U_x$ of $Y$ having diameter less than $\epsilon$. [For example, choose $V_x$ so that $f(V_x)$ lies in the $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$-neighborhood of $f(x)$. Then $f(\bar{V}_x)$ lies in the $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$-neighborhood of $f(x)$, which has diameter at most $\frac{2\epsilon}{3}$.]

where $f$ is a continuous function. I understand that the continuity of $f$ allows us to choose $V_x$ such that $f(V_x)\subset B(f(x),\frac{\epsilon}{4})$, but I do not know how to use this statement to reach the conclusion that "$f(\bar{V}_x)$ lies in the $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$-neighborhood of $f(x)$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(V_x)\subset B(f(x),\frac{\epsilon}{4})
$, we have that $\overline{f(V_x)} \subset \overline{B(f(x),\frac{\epsilon}{4})} $. Since $\frac{\epsilon}{4}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$, we  know that $\overline{B(f(x),\frac{\epsilon}{4})} \subset B(f(x),\frac{\epsilon}{3})$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have that $f(\overline{V_x}) \subset \overline{f(V_x)}$ (Theorem 18.1). We combine to conclude that we have $f(\overline{V_x}) \subset B(f(x),\frac{\epsilon}{3})$.